# How to read AngularJs locale file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, locale

I am using Angular bootstrap [datepicker popup](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepickerPopup) and I want to set the date format of the textbox according to the locale, so my idea is reading the property "shortdate" from locale file and set it in the format property.

So my question is, **how can I read the locale file?** This file is present, localization is actually working and you can see the file in the network tab of the browser's developer tools

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized there is no need to read anything, as the locale is already loaded by Angular you have all data available in the $locale service.

```
this.format = $locale.DATETIME_FORMATS.shortDate;
```

In my case this format variable is being assigned to uib-datepicker-popup like this:

```
<input type="text" uib-datepicker-popup="{{vm.format}}"
ng-model="vm.model" datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions"
ng-required="vm.isRequired" ng-disabled="vm.isDisabled"/>
```

Silly question, I hope it may help to some other clueless in future :)

Answer (score 0):

I once had the same requirement and end up using the 'tmh.dynamicLocale' module ([see here](https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale).

Using this module, you'll first have to configure a locale provider. In an angular config function, inject 'tmhDynamicLocaleProvider' and call the localeLocationPattern( ) function to define the pattern to use to access your locale files.

For instance:

```
 tmhDynamicLocaleProvider.localeLocationPattern('vendor/angular/locale/angular-locale_{{locale}}-{{locale}}.js');
```

Then, whenever the locale is supposed to changed, you simply have to inject 'tmhDynamicLocale' in your service/controller/... and call the set( ) function on in, passing as argument, the locale you want to switch to.

Hope that'll help you.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't expect any change in locale. Locale will be the same, I just need to read this locale to update the format of datepicker popup.

Comment: It's up to you to call the set( ) function without any actual locale change. In one application I worked on, I loaded a different locale file depending on the language the user picked in the application, so that the labels in the datepicker widget are accordingly translated.

Comment: But the issues is that datepicker is not using localization to set the format, it has a property which has to be manually set. It doesn't matter which locale you load, they will be ignored by this component, so to set properly I would like to read the locale and then set manually.